# How to make rounded Tabs in React Native Base?

Tags: background, tabs, react-native, rounding, customization

How to make rounded Tabs in React Native Base?
I have made rounded Tabs by using radius property.But it's still showing behind background color.

[image]

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your code with us would be helpful to find which of your components has a blue background that shows up when you apply the rounded corners.

You could try setting the background of that component to white or transparent